# C# EF6 make multiple async calls to one context using Unity - Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asynchronous, unity-container

I get the following error when visiting my SPA site which makes some calls to the API when loaded:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

If I don't use the same context and try to update values I get the following error, see this question:

[Entity Framework 6 - Dependency Injection with Unity - Repository pattern - Add or Update exception for many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030136/entity-framework-6-dependency-injection-with-unity-repository-pattern-add)

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

This means that I can't use the answer suggested here to use multiple contexts:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20635076/3850405

UnityConfig.cs:

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISupplierRepository, SupplierRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi, please show the code that throws the error.

Comment: @MihailStancescu Various API calls, since they are async it can be any method of those that are called when the site is loaded. See this for architecture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030136/entity-framework-6-dependency-injection-with-unity-repository-pattern-add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with `PerRequestLifetimeManager` from `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc`.

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISupplierRepository, SupplierRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
```