# ASP.NET Core MVC inject per request

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, tdd, moq

I am looking forward to inject RequestContext, per request in .Net Core. inside the service collection.

Someone attempted 8 yrs. ago.
[ASP.NET MVC inject per request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899304/asp-net-mvc-inject-per-request)

```
public interface IMvcDepency
    {
        string PathValue { get; set; }
    }

public class FakeMvcDepency : IMvcDepency
{
    public string PathValue { get; set; }
}

public class MvcDepency : IMvcDepency
{
    public string PathValue { get; set; }

    public MvcDepency(HttpRequest req)
    {
        PathValue = req.Path.Value;
    }
}
```

And inject it somewhere in startup, as follows:

```
services.AddTransient<IMvcDepency, MvcDepency>(x => x.???);
```

or in OnActionExecuting like below:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actCtx)
    {
        MvcDepency mvcDepency = actCtx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IMvcDepency)) as MvcDepency;
        mvcDepency = new MvcDepency(actCtx.HttpContext.Request);
        actCtx.HttpContext.RequestServices.AddService(mvcDepency);// AddService method doesn't in exist
      }
```

**Current Error:**
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest' while attempting to activate 'CAWP.Api.Controllers.MvcDepency'.'

Comment: You mean something like this? https://www.strathweb.com/2016/12/accessing-httpcontext-outside-of-framework-components-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

Controllers already have access to the `HttpRequest` object in each of the methods via the base class. But it is only available once a method is called (for obvious reasons!). If you want to wrap it in your own class then you can do it in the `OnActionExecuting` override.

You can create a new `MvcDepency` class in `OnActionExecuting` and reference it in the code. As controllers are created per request you should be able to use a class variable to store the reference.

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private IMvcDepency _depency;

    public ValuesController()
    {
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        _depency = new MvcDepency(context.HttpContext.Request);

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        var path = _depency.PathValue;

        return new string[] { "PathValue", path };
    }
}
```

This should result in the `MvcDepency` class having access to the `HttpRequest` object.
You should add a factory class for your `IMvcDepency` interface to avoid the `new` in `OnActionExecuting`.