# Can session call dispose method on session ending time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to know if IDisposable objects will dispose on session ending.

I know, I can dispose on Session ending event myself. But I want to write an IDisposable class.

For example, I have

```
public class MyObject : IDisposable
{
    // some properties

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // disposing
    }
}
```

and I need to dispose this object on session ending time :

```
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["key"] != null)
            ((MyObject)Session["key"]).Dispose();
    }
```

So, I want to know on session ending time that operation will automatically or I need write as above.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make too much sense. Maybe you can show us what you need with some code?

Comment: It does not make any sense to put object which need to be disposed in your session. Try to put only Data objects in your session without any businesslogic.

Comment: I already set Session["key"] = new MyObject();

Comment: So, Session doesn't call Dispose method, does it?

Comment: More answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/498095/11683

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session_End does not automatically dispose of IDisposable objects, so your Session_End solution is correct.

However:

- Session_End is only called when you use "inproc" sessions (but for the other types you would need a serializable object)
- It's only called after the session timeout has expired, so you kept this resource for an extra 20 minutes (or whatever your timeout is)

So try and find a solution that doesn't require you to store IDisposable objects in Session.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of a class which implements the `IDisposable` interface will only be "disposed" whenever you call the `Dispose` method, whether directly or indirectly via the `using` construct. It's not something which happens automatically whenever an object falls out of scope.

For example, this would be bad practice;

```
public void SomeMethodCalledDuringSession()
{
    var resourceHog = new ResourceHog(); // where ResourceHog : IDisposable
    // Perform operations
}
```

The object is never disposed properly here, regardless of your ASP.NET session ending. However, you can call `Dispose` directly when you're finished, or a better idea is to do this;

```
public void SomeMethodCalledDuringSession()
{
    using(var resourceHog = new ResourceHog()) // where ResourceHog : IDisposable
    {
        // Perform operations
    }
}
```

This translates into a `try ... finally` pattern, with the call to `Dispose` in the `finally` clause, ensuring that it gets called (apart from a few rare situations).

**Edit**: I would also read this; http://nitoprograms.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/how-to-implement-idisposable-and.html