# What is the way to perform some session cleanup logic regardless of user logout/timeout/browser close?

Tags: asp.net, .net, session

I have an IIS hosted web application with a C# backend.

When a user logs in, I want to instantiate an instance of `HttpClient()` for the logged in user to communicate with the back-end over a REST API.  Once that client is created, the backend will initialize some user-specific memory which should be cleared once the user has logged out (that is, the `HttpClient()` object is disposed).

It seems like the right thing to do here is to instantiate that `HttpClient()` object at log-in, and then have some code that is called when either the user manually logs out or the user session times out or the user closes the browser, and that code will dispose of the `HttpClient()` manually.

This is surely a well-travelled problem, so there must be an elegant solution to it.  How can I dispose of this user-specific `HttpClient()` when any possible log-out scenario occurs (manual/timeout/browser close)?

Comment: Need confirmation: 1- your Web application is not notified when the browser is closed. 2- if you store the HttpClient Object in your session it will be automatically disposed when session ends. So all you have to do is to call Session.Abandon() when the user manually logout

Comment: Dady has it... if you store it in the Session object, Session.Abandon() will do all of the required cleanup, and it is fired automatically when the session ends... you simply need to force-end the session on logout.

Comment: `If you store the HttpClient Object in your session it will be automatically disposed when session ends.`  [To my knowledge this is **not true**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498095/session-containing-items-implementing-idisposable).  I highly recommend you don't store HttpClient in the session, it really doesn't add any true benefit and adds a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a class which performs the user-specific memory functions you want to perform. This class would contain a method which instantiates the HttpClient() object and then performs the user-specific operations(functions). This class would also contain another method which clears the user-specific memory functions i.e. it disposes the HttpClient() object and performs cleanup of any user-specific data.

So, essentially, you code would look like this:

```
public class HttpHelper
{

    public void LoadUserInformation()
    {
       HttpClient httpClientObj = new HttpClient();
       //perform user-specific tasks
       //your logic here

       //Store the httpClientObj object in session
    }

    public void DisposeUserInformation()
    {
       //Fetch the httpClientObj from session
       //perform user-specific tasks
       //your logic here
       httpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now, in either of the scenarios, whether the session times out or the user logs out, you could call the DisposeUserInformation() method and that would handle both of your scenario's be it session timing out or user logging out.

There is a Session_End() method in global.asax. The global.asax file will be wired to call this method when the session ends. You can call the DisposeUserInformation() method there.

You could also call this method on the logout button click in the controller.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Handling the departure of a web user is not trivial, as the HTTP protocol is stateless. The server can never be certain if the user is still there; a HTTP connection that gets closed doesn't mean that user have to have gone away, and the server can think that a connection is still open eventhough the user is no longer there.

Unless you will be using the `HttpClient` object intensly, so that you expect that keeping it alive would save a lot of resources, you should just dispose it at the end of each REST request, and open a new one for the next request.

A web request normally takes a short time to handle, and most resources used for it is freed when the request is gone. That make most of the objects short lived, and those are the ones that the garbage collector handles most efficiently. Holding on to objects across several requests makes them very long lived, which uses up memory on the server, and make the garbage collector work harder. Unless there is a specific reason to hold on to an object, you shouldn't let it live longer than it takes to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't recommend storing anything `IDisposable` in the session.  What if in the process of downloading from the Web APi, in another window the user clicks *Logout*, you disposed of the HttpClient while it's in use.  That is a small edge-case, but there can be plenty of edge cases with storing `IDisposable` in session.  Also if you need to scale out to multiple servers, that requires storing Session in something other than in-proc which requires the object to be serializable (which HttpClient is not).

Instead:

```
[serializable]
public sealed class ApiClient
{
  public ApiClient(uri baseAddress)
  {
    this._BaseAddress = baseAddress;
  }

  public Uri BaseAddress { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
  {
    var address = new Uri(this.BaseAddress, "Employees/Persons");

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
      // something like this
      var task = GetStringAsync(address);
      await task;
      var json = task.Result;
    }
  }
}
```

Nice session wrapper:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
public static bool TryGetValue<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, out T value)
      where T : class
{
    var name = typeof(T).FullName;

    value = session[name] as T;

    var result = value != null;

    return result;
}

public static void SetValue<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, T value)
{
    var name = typeof(T).FullName;

    session[name] = value;
}

public static void RemoveValue<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
{
    var name = typeof(T).FullName;

    session[name] = null;
}

public static bool ValueExists(this HttpSessionStateBase session, Type objectType)
{
    var name = objectType.FullName;

    var result = session[name] != null;

    return result;
}
}
```

Now you can create the api per client:

```
Session.SetValue(new ApiClient(new Uri("http://localhost:443")));
```

Somewhere else you can get persons:

```
ApiClient client;

if (Session.TryGetValue(out client))
{
  client.GetPersons();
}
```